# Image not appearing, shows 0 x 0 pixels

Tags: html, css

The image is not showing, and when I inspect element, it shows "0 x 0 pixels (Natural 620px x 480px)".  Putting a display:block on the img didn't help.  How can I fix this?

The test site is below, image should appear on the left under the "FREE SHIPPING ON ORDERS OVER $99" promo.

```
(link removed)
```

Comment: Could you at least tell the image name? And the things you did to investigate the issue? Using the dev console, there are three images not found (404).

Comment: Are you running Ghostery in your browser? If I turn that off, the image starts appearing.

Comment: @DanFromGermany The image name is fitz-shopdinnerware.jpg

Comment: @Overv, I'm not familiar with that, what is Ghostery and how do I turn it off?

Comment: The image does appear on my end under the 'FREE SHIPPINGON ORDERS OVER $99*' heading.

Comment: @isosmall It is a browser extension that hides ads in webpages (amongst other things). Are you sure you're not running an extension like that?

Comment: Hey, give us a hint, does "the image" have a name or re we supposed to guess? You need to  post the relevant code!

Comment: @Overv It works when I turn off the Ad-block Chrome extension, thank you, you were pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image appears for me if I turn off the Chrome extension Ghostery, which you are probably running as well (or a similar ad blocking extension). The image is classified as an advertisement and therefore hidden.

Comment: You all are right, I turned off Ad-block and it appears!  Thank you!